# Intercepting TeamSpeak output in C#

Tags: c#, audio, intercept

first I'd wanna say this is my first question here, I'll try to comply to the asking tips the best I can... Also I couldn't find a way to post this in a specific C# section so I just used it in the title.

What I'm trying to accomplish is intercepting the sound output of TeamSpeak, and figuring out which person on the channel is producing the loudest sound. I had a look at TeamSpeak SDK but it's more intended for building your own VoIP software than fooling around with TeamSpeak itself...

At first I'm just going to make a simple program that shows the names of the persons and a dB bar (or something that represents loudness) next to them.

I was surprised to see there isn't much discussion around this, I think there's a lot of cool snippets to be made (this one will be for kicking spastics swiftly.)

Comment: I think You should ask the TeamSpeak SDK developers about it.